# datetime formatting in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, formatting

When I generate a date with the following code

```
var date = new Date();
```

I get a date-time of the following form

```
Sat May 11 2013 21:54:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Can anyone tell me how to generate a date of the form below without using regex/string functions.

```
Sat May 11 2013 21:54:23
```

Comment: The formatting of `new Date` is implementation dependent, so you'd be better off making up your own string from the UTC epoch timestamp.  Why don't you want to (or can't) use regular expressions/string formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not come with a date formatting library beyond the one specific format you see.  You can either build your own by piecing together the exact pieces you want and adding the strings together or you can get a third party date formatting library.

If you want a 3rd party library, the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library is pretty thorough.  In that library, it would be:

```
Date.today().toString("ddd MMM d yyyy H:mm:ss");
```

You could, of course obtain all the component values from the built-in date object and then build your own string too.

Without adding a library, you'd have to write your own way to make that specific format:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    function makeTwoDigits(val) {
        var prefix = val <= 9 ? "0" : "";
        return prefix + val;
    }
    var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();                  // 0-6, 0=Sunday
    var month = date.getMonth();                    // 0-11
    var day = date.getDate();                       // 1-31
    var year = date.getFullYear();                  // 2013
    var hours = makeTwoDigits(date.getHours());     // 0-23
    var mins = makeTwoDigits(date.getMinutes());    // 0-59
    var secs = makeTwoDigits(date.getSeconds());    // 0-59

    var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    return days[dayOfWeek] + " " + months[month] + " " + day + " " + year + " " +
           hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zu7Uz/

Comment: @benpearce - I added a custom function to produce the desired date format.

Comment: @benpearce - Updated my function to pad leading zeroes where that is normally done.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving this a shot: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

It has a collection of Date format options that I believe would give you what you desire.

---

Ignoring the above Javascript library and doing it native:

```
var date = new Date();
date = date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
```

Does this work ok for you?

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'd love to achieve this with out adding a library.

Comment: Oh! I think I've found something for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPXa/ Here is the stackoverflow link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184618/javascript-asp-net-date-format-without-timezone-info-timezone-offsets **edit:** I just noticed it didn't include your hour,min and second requirement so I updated the fiddle and and here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPXa/18/